# Using Notepad++ as an IDE: building from ground up

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, notepad++

I'm programming off *Notepad++* at the moment and liking it, purely because i am seeing everything happen and why, including CSS3, HTML5, and learning Python, C++ etc

I've used a few IDE-s and appreciate them, but if i were to build a relatively simple site using Notepad++ what would i need to link everything up, like the design interface, Python code, CSS etc straight out of the text editor?

Answer (score 2):

You will almost certainly need the NppExec plugin.  This gives Notepad++ (NPP) tremendous flexibility.

With it, you can:

- Run python, ruby, perl scripts from within NPP
- See the output in the NPP console window
- Popup an input box to prompt for paramters, and pass these parameters to a script
- Store output from a script and insert it into the current NPP file
- Pass highlighted text from current NPP file to a running script
- Filter output from a script and hook onto lines in the current NPP file,
- and probably much more...

[Here's an example](https://superuser.com/q/463751/153054) I wrote to get NPP to generate custom timestamps.  The code illustrates how to do several of the above capabilities.  ( https://superuser.com/q/463751/153054 )

In short, NppExec is an engine that allows you to integrate features that you want to have in your development environment.  With a little effort, you'll find you're limited only by your own imagination (and of course time!)

To see the capabilities NppExec provides, pop open a console window in NPP, and type `help`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as Notepad++ I think it has almost all the tools in built in it even an FTP. If you see something that you need and is missing may be you can try searching for [Notepad++ PLugins](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/)